# remove node from array spritekit swift

Tags: arrays, swift, skspritenode, removeclass

I'm working a little game for iOS (spritekit/swift).

I've an array of *SKSpriteNode* in my scene defined like this:

```
var spritesTree = [SKSpriteNode]()
```

then I fill the array with a function and add them to the scene like this:

```
spritesTree = spritesCollectionTree(count: numTrees)
    for sprite in spritesTree {
        addChild(sprite)
    }
```

After that, depending the situation the process adds some more trees into the array. I Know how to remove elements from the scene and the array if I Know the index

```
            spritesTree[i].removeFromParent()
            spritesTree.removeAtIndex(i)
```

but my problem is to remove an especific node in this array when I don't Know the index. For exemple when one of the the sprite was touched

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let positionInScene = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene)
```

In this case, ¿How can I remove the touchedNode from my array *spritesTree* of *SKSpriteNode* if I don't know the index? I read something about *indexOf* to find the index previoustly but it doesn't work with my *SKSpriteNode* array. Could you help me please?

Bests,

Answer (score 0):

You can create a name for each SKSpriteNode :

```
spritesTree[index].name = String(index)
```

After when you check node touched you convert name to Int

```
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let positionInScene = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene)
    var index = Int(touchedNode.name)
    touchedNode.removeFromParent()
    spritesTree.removeAtIndex(index)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn’t solve my problem entirely. Imagine I’ve the following list node names ["0","1","2","3","4"] that match with the positions. When I remove first Item with name ‘2’ everything is ok but if then I try to _removeAtIndex_ with name ‘4’ it fails because the items have been reorganized with positions 0->"0", 1->"1", 2->"3", 3->"4" and now there is no "4" position in the array. Do you know if there is any function that returns the item position from the name?

Comment: rename all after delete in the loop. Or you can try to find the node into array like this : for index in 0...spritesTree.count { if touchedNode == spritesTree[index] { spritesTree.removeAtIndex(index) }  }